# Simplfying expression using order of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a, b, c$ are group elements with $|a| =5, |b| = 8, |c| =3$, expand and then simplify $(b^5a^3c^2b^7)^{-2}$, expressing it without negative exponents.

This is what I have: (Verify please)

$$|a| =5 \rightarrow a^5 = e$$
$$|b| = 8 \rightarrow b^8 = e$$
$$|c| = 3 \rightarrow c^3 = e$$
$$(b^5a^3c^2b^7)^{-2} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{b^{10}a^6c^4b^{14}}$$

$b^{10} = b^8b^2 = eb^2 = b^2$

$a^6 = a^5a = ea = a$

$c^4 = c^3c=ec=c$

$b^{14} = b^8b^6 = eb^6=b^6$.

So now we have, $\displaystyle\frac{1}{b^2acb^6}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better idea is to use that, say, $b^{-10}=b^ {-2}=b^6$. Then we can use
$$
(b^5a^3c^2b^7)^{-2}=b^{-14}c^{-4}a^{-6}b^{-10}
$$
and then convert to positive exponents.

Comment: but $b^{10}$ does not equal $b^8b^{-2}$. so how are you using that to simplify

Comment: the way i am looking at it is: $b^{-14} = b^{-8}b^6=(b^8)^{-1}b^6=e^{-1}b^6=b^6$ and so on for all the others.

Comment: then $b^{-14}c^{-4}a^{-6}b^{-10} = b^6cab^2$...

Comment: This is wrong: we have $b^{-14}\neq b^{-8}b^6$. You mean, $b^{-14}=b^{-6}=b^2$.

Comment: $b^{-14}=b^{-8}b^{-6}$...my fault

Comment: so after fixing all of my calculation, with your help, i obtain $b^2c^2a^4b^6$. correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.